# Python - Folium Search Plugin Doesn't Search Popup Text in MarkerCluster Group Layer

Tags: python, search, folium

My folium map, marker cluster, layer control, and search bar all work and show up correctly except for actually using the search bar. The layer I have the search plugin point to when searching is my MarkerCluster layer, which the folium documentation says should be searchable. Anything I type into the search bar it returns "Location not found" which makes me think it's not searching through the MarkerCluster layer correctly, or does not know to search through the *text* of that layer that is included in the markers' popups.

Here is my code as I have it right now:

```
import os 
import folium
from folium import plugins
import pandas as pd
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
from folium.plugins import Search

#import data including lat/lon, name of service, address of service
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

#Create base map zoomed in to Indiana
map=folium.Map(location=[39.80, -86.12],  tiles=None, zoom_start=7)
folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron', name='COVID-19 Services').add_to(map)

#Make Marker Cluster Group layer
mcg = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster(control=False)
map.add_child(mcg)

#Create layer of markers
#Set marker popups to display name and address of service
for row in df.iterrows():
    row_values=row[1]
    location=[row_values['latitude'], row_values['longitude']]
    popup=popup=(row_values['name']+'<br>'+'<br>'+row_values['address_1']+
                 '<br>'+'<br>'+row_values['city']+','+' '+row_values['state']+
                 '<br>'+row_values['zip'])
    marker=folium.Marker(location=location, popup=popup, min_width=2000)
    marker.add_to(mcg)

#Add search bar
servicesearch = Search(
    layer=mcg,
    geom_type='Point',
    placeholder='Search for a service',
    collapsed=False,
).add_to(map)

#Add layer control
folium.LayerControl().add_to(map)

map
```

How do I get the search plugin to actually search the test of the marker popups? Then, how do I get the map to highlight or zoom to those searched for markers? Any help is GREATLY appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```py
def visualize_locations_with_marker_cluster(df, zoom=4):
    f = folium.Figure(width=1000, height=500)

    center_lat=34.686567
    center_lon=135.52000

    m = folium.Map([center_lat,center_lon], zoom_start=zoom).add_to(f)
    marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(m)

    for d in df.iterrows():
        folium.Marker(location=[d[1]["y"], d[1]["x"]], popup=d[1]["company"], name=d[1]["company"]).add_to(marker_cluster)

    servicesearch = Search(
        layer=marker_cluster,
        search_label="name",
        placeholder='Search for a service',
        collapsed=False,
    ).add_to(m)


    return m
```

First create map, create cluster, loop values in `pd.dataframe` and create `Mareker`s for Cluster with `name` label.
Next create `Search` object and add cluster there with `search_label="name",` label. Finally add it all back to the map

`["x", "y"]` is longtitude and latitude, `company` is a search value in my case

Answer (score 0):

If you change a little how you add data to the map, it will be easier to use the search bar. You can change the data in your dataframe into a GeoJSON objet. You first need to create a dictionnary for your GeoJSON and use the function `folium.GeoJSON()` :

```
geo_json = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [],
}
for d in df.iterrows():
    temp_dict = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates":[d[1]["longitude"], d[1]["latitude"]],
        
      },"properties": {"name": d[1]["name"]}
    }
    geo_json["features"].append(temp_dict)
geojson_obj = folium.GeoJson(geo_json).add_to(map)
```

After that, you just need to change a little your code to add the search bar :

```
servicesearch = Search(
    layer=geojson_obj,
    search_label="name",
    placeholder='Search for a service',
    collapsed=False,
).add_to(map)
```

Comment: This solution still did not solve the search issue and now my markers are not clustered and don't have the popups anymore. It seems like the search plugin likes GeoJson layers more than MarkerCluster layers (despite the documentation saying the search plugin works on MarkerCluster layers), so this is a good start. Any suggestions on how to now take this GeoJson data file and still have the markers cluster and the popups still be there?

Comment: @Pierre-Loic, I tried this on my own data set, and it maps the markers off map in a weird row after selecting a searched "name" any thoughts?

Comment: @onxx, you can check the value of name that you have in your geo_json because the Search bar uses this label to work

Comment: @Pierre-Loic, how do I tie that back to the marker?

Comment: This is a nice solution for small dataset, but in my case where have over 10000+ coordinates, its very sluggish. I have to use MarkerCluster

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling a while with the same. I believer this might fix it: add a 'name' or whatever you want to be searched to the marker, e.g.:

```
marker=folium.Marker(location=location, popup=popup, min_width=2000, name=name)
```

A little late, but better than never, perhaps.